# How to match an XML attribute on containing a specified value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, selector

I wish to know how it's possible to check if an XML attribute contains a specified value; I mean something like `('[attribute~="value"]')` but for XML attributes.

I tried using some external plugins but nothing. Maybe a regular expression could be an option?

Any help will be strongly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: That should work if you parse the XML with jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

once you have parsed the `XML` using [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) you get a jquery object on which you can do something like

```
$($xml).find("[attribute~="value"]");
```